# Member functions more efficient than binary operator overloads in C++?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Consider two ways to implement addition on variables of a class Foo:

1. Using operator overloading: `Foo operator+(const Foo& rhs)`
2. Using a member function: `void addAndAssign(const Foo &lhs, const Foo& rhs)`

Now consider the two equivalent expressions `a = b + c` and `a.addAndAssign(b,c)`:

Option 1 will put the result of addition into a new variable, which is then move-assigned into the destination `a`. But Option 2 will perform addition directly into variable `a` without assignment.

Remember, move assignment can't really avoid copying data on classes that have statically allocated members. Doesn't this make binary operators always less efficient than a equivalent member function for types that contain statically allocated member variables and arrays? Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: Do you know [Expression_templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates)? How do you implement `addAndAssign`?

Comment: *Remember, move assignment can't really avoid copying data on classes that have static members.* What do static member have to do with copying?

Comment: Missing some `const` BTW.

Comment: How move/copy cheap/expensive for your class?

Comment: For efficiency questions:  profile, profile, profile.  The only way to determine efficiency is to measure it, on your platform, with optimized code.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen when you have dynamically allocated members, during move assignment, you can copy the pointers of the members of the r-value variable and that constitutes a 'move'. Instead, when you have static members in your class, the only thing you CAN do during a move-assignment is copy all the data from the r-value argument.

Comment: @Jarod42 I'm working with matrices (implemented with static arrays). So that extra copy is very expensive. Why not use dynamic allocation? Because I frequently need to pack arrays of them together to create a binary blob and I want to avoid copying bytes one by one into a new buffer.

Comment: @Jarod42 I don't know much about expression templates. But it looks like they were designed to solve exactly this problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Jarod42 _How do you implement addAndAssign_ Simply `this->floatMember = lhs.floatMember + rhs.floatMember`

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. Static class member is common for all instances of the class. Copying or moving an object doesn't affect it (unless you write code to affect it). I cannot imagine an implementation of matrix that uses static arrays for anything. In my opinion, the question is unanswerable, because you are asking with some assumptions in mind that we do not know.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Sorry, I meant statically allocated members (as opposed to dynamically allocated using new/delete). i.e., conventional variables `float floatMember;`.

Answer (score 0):

So i have written a very simple benchmark, that simply adds two Vector3s together in different ways.

Method 1:

> ```
> static Vector3 Add(Vector3 a, Vector3 b) {
>     return Vector3(a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y, a.z + b.z);
> }
> ```

Method 2:

> ```
> Vector3 operator+(const Vector3& right) const {
>     return Vector3(this->x + right.x, this->y + right.y, this->z + right.z);
> }
> ```

Method 3:

> ```
> Vector3& AddTo(Vector3 other) {
>     x += other.x, y += other.y, z += other.z;
>     return *this;
> }
> ```

Method 4:

> ```
> Vector3& operator+=(const Vector3 rhs) {
>     this->x += rhs.x, this->y += rhs.y, this->z += rhs.z;
>     return *this;
> }
> ```

Testing sets are two Arrays of Vector3s, both 10Mio entries, randomly initialized in the Range from -10k to 10k. IDE is VS 2019 and Default(ISO C++ 14 Standard) On Ryzen 3700x CPU, 24GB 2800mhz CL16 RAM

Results are:

Method 1: 432 ms

Method 2: 438 ms

Method 3: 227 ms

Method 4: 227 ms

I re-ran this a few times and the Results seem to be pretty much fixed (1 - 2 ms more ore less here or there)

But it makes sense, that it virtually does not change the performance. Both the overload and the function are the same code internally and if you compile it down an operator overload is basically a function. Yet the simple Add function consitently is a few ms better. But it really only shows whenn adding 30Mio times in a row.

Comment: You might want to check the output of `void addAndAssign(Vector3& lhs, Vector3& rhs) {x = lhs.x + rhs.x; y = lhs.y + rhs.y; z = lhs.z + rhs.z; }`. This is a member function of Vector3 and you'd call it like so: `a.addAndAssign(b,c);`

Comment: Okay yeah i changed it to be of type void and it still didnt change the result a bit . Its the same

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I just measured it too. Without compiler optimizations there is a HUGE difference but with compiler optimizations, there is almost none.